# Boost asio async_write from 2 different threads

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I would like to have a TCP server receiving data in one thread and being able to send data from another one.

My code does echo what the server receives, so it's possible to write from the same thread but fails to send messages from the main.

I believe it has something to do with the socket not accessible but I need a push to get back on track, thanks!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    do_read();
  }

  void write(char *msg, std::size_t length)
  {
    do_write(msg, length);
  }

private:
  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(data_, length);
          }
        });
  }

  void do_write(char *msg, std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
          else
          {
            std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
            std::cout << socket_.is_open() << std::endl;
          }
        });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
      socket_(io_service)
  {
    do_accept();
  }

  void send(char *msg, std::size_t length)
  {
    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->write(msg, length);
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    server s(io_service, std::atoi(argv[1]));

    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service));
    std::thread t1([&io_service]() {io_service.run();});

    char msg[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };

    while(1)
    { 
      sleep(5);
      s.send(msg, 4);
    }

    t1.join();
    std::cout << "t1 joined " << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: asio obejcts are not thread safe, you shouldn't use them from multiple threads at the same time, additionally you shouldn't call `async_write` when there is already another `async_write` pending

Comment: Okay, what are my options then? I can think of feeding a buffer with the messages to be sent and call recursively async_write but how can I trigger a send when the message queue goes from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: The approach I've used in the past is as you say recursively call `async_write` and when adding messages to the queue if the queue was empty triggering the first call to `async_write`, obviously this will then need some form of thread protection, either a mutex (generally a bad idea in async code) or by using a strand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need some synchronization. I'd suggest to put each client on a strand:

```
void do_accept() {
  acceptor_.async_accept(make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()),
                         [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                           if (!ec) {
                             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(s))->start();
                           }

                           do_accept();
                         });
}
```

Next up, you want to modify the `write()` member function to post to the strand:

```
 void write(char const* msg, size_t length)
 {
    post(socket_.get_executor(), [this, =] {
        do_write(msg, length); });
 }
```

Note that this is not enough. `async_write` is a composed operation and you [cannot overlap writes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html):

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.

The common approach here is to create a queue:

```
  std::deque<std::string> outbox_;

  void do_write(std::string msg) {
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
    if (outbox_.size() == 1)
      do_write_loop();
  }
```

The queue provides reference stability (important to keep the buffers valid). The write_loop is only started at the first element queued, and keeps writing until the queue is empty:

```
  void do_write_loop() {
    if (outbox_.empty())
      return;
    
    async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outbox_.front()),
                [this, self](error_code ec, size_t length) {
                  if (!ec) {
                    outbox_.pop_front();
                    do_write_loop();
                  } else {
                    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << socket_.is_open() << std::endl;
                  }
                });
  }
```

Now, your `server::write` was a bit funny. It created a **new** session, moving **again** from the `socket_` variable (which I removed in the process of adding the strand earlier). That would never have done anything useful. I'm guessing that you **might** have expected it to send to *all* connected sessions. In that case:

```
  void send(char const* msg, size_t length) const
  {
    for (Handle const& handle: _sessions)
      if (auto const sess = handle.lock())
        sess->write(msg, length);
  }
```

Of course, you need something to contain the sessions:

```
 private:
  using Handle = std::weak_ptr<session>;
  std::list<Handle> _sessions;
```

And to store the sessions there in `do_accept`:

```
      auto sess = std::make_shared<session>(std::move(s));
      _sessions.emplace_back(sess);
      sess->start();
```

Optionally, you might want to clean up disconnected sessions:

```
      _sessions.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&Handle::expired));
```

Now, we're not done, because just like `session`, `server` needs a strand to make all these operations thread-safe (with respect to `sessions_`):

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5b4cceead8a9b0e)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
 public:
  session(tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    do_read();
  }

  void write(char const* msg, size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    post(socket_.get_executor(),
      [this, msg = std::string(msg, length)]() mutable { do_write(std::move(msg)); });
  }

 private:
  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_), [this, self](error_code ec, size_t length) {
      if (!ec)
      {
        write(data_.data(), length);
        do_read();
      }
    });
  }

  std::deque<std::string> outbox_;

  void do_write(std::string msg)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());

    outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
    if (outbox_.size() == 1)
      do_write_loop();
  }

  void do_write_loop()
  {
    if (outbox_.empty())
      return;

    auto self(shared_from_this());

    async_write(
      socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outbox_.front()), [this, self](error_code ec, size_t length) {
        if (!ec)
        {
          outbox_.pop_front();
          do_write_loop();
        }
        else
        {
          std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
          std::cout << socket_.is_open() << std::endl;
        }
      });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  std::array<char, 1024> data_;
};

class server
{
 public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : acceptor_(make_strand(io_service), tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    acceptor_.listen();
    do_accept();
  }

  void send(char const* msg, size_t length)
  {
    post(acceptor_.get_executor(), [this, msg = std::string(msg, length)]() mutable {
      for (Handle const& handle : _sessions)
        if (auto const sess = handle.lock())
          sess->write(msg.data(), msg.size());
    });
  }

 private:
  using Handle = std::weak_ptr<session>;
  std::list<Handle> _sessions;

  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
      make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
        if (!ec)
        {
          auto sess = std::make_shared<session>(std::move(s));
          _sessions.emplace_back(sess);
          sess->start();

          _sessions.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&Handle::expired));
        }

        do_accept();
      });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_server <port>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    server s(io_service, std::atoi(argv[1]));

    auto work = make_work_guard(io_service);
    std::thread t1([&io_service]() { io_service.run(); });

    char constexpr msg[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};

    while (true)
    {
      sleep_for(5s);
      s.send(msg, 4);
    }

    t1.join();
    std::cout << "t1 joined " << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception const& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sure it will help many people struggling! Boost has many examples but I couldn't find one that suits my needs